# implement mouse multi component selection java swing

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, mouselistener, jcomponent

I would like to implement the mouse selection in java in order to obtain the component multiselction in a JPanel, but I'm still struggling to understand if it is possible.
In my case I got a Jpanel with a matrix(I have not used a Jtable for space need) of JButtons and my idea is to allow the user to select a subset of JButton in a row/column at the same time. 
I tought that a good option can be to draw a trasparent rectangule with mouse and than get all components that fall in the rectangule but I'm not sure whether this solution can be a good well-functioning solution.

Any suggestion about it? Do you have any other better solution or advise?

Thanks in advances

Comment: You may be looking to implement a [`ListSelectionModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ListSelectionModel.html).

Comment: Unfortunatelly is not a table, and over it I need that the user can select a sub set oj Jbutton in the column or in the row.

Comment: You could use the glass pane, registering a `MouseListener` to it and monitor for mouse drags, the problem with this is it will block the mouse events